# Use sed to replace some string in a file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file with contents like below:

```
 {
  "applications": [
    {
      "id": 2537302,
      "name": "addressdb_prod",
      "language": "dotnet",
      "health_status": "unknown",
      "reporting": true,
      "last_reported_at": "2017-08-03T10:41:52+00:00",
      "application_summary": {
      "response_time": 5.04,
      more content here....
      and finally the following lines towards the end of the file
     },
      "links": {
        "application_instances": [],
        "servers": [],
        "application_hosts": []
      }
    }
    ],
  "links": {
    "application.servers": "/v2/servers?ids={server_ids}",
    "application.server": "/v2/servers/{server_id}",
    "application.application_hosts": "/v2/application/{application_id}/hosts?ids={host_ids}",
    "application.application_host": "/v2/application/{application_id}/hosts/{host_id}",
    "application.application_instances": "/v2/application/{application_id}/instances?ids={instance_ids}",
    "application.application_instance": "/v2/application/{application_id}/instances/{instance_id}",
    "application.alert_policy": "/v2/alert_policies/{alert_policy_id}"
  }
}
```

What I would like is run `sed` command to strip out below parts:

```
{
  "applications": [
```

from the beginning of the file, and also anything starting from below parts till end of the file.

```
],
  "links": {
```

Comment: You will be better off using a JSON parser to do this.

Comment: @ashabc question is not very clear. You need to place the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your file doesn't contain any other lines starting with `],` it's pretty simple to define two ranges to be deleted:

```
sed '1,/"applications": \[/d
     /^[[:blank:]]*\],/,$d' yourfile
```

Comment: Philipos, this command does not run. @Rakesh Sharma, I want to strip off some unwanted texts both from the beginning as well as end of the file as mentioned above

Comment: @ashabc What do you mean by "does not run"? No output, wrong output, error message, machine exploding?

Comment: This is the error message I get it when I try to run the command you specified. sed: -e expression #1, char 45: unknown command: `,'

Comment: I used head and tail command to remove first two lines and last 11 lines. That worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to escape the `[`. I'm glad you could help yourself.